# Deleting parent entity using cascade rule in EF5

Tags: entity-framework

I am creating a code in which I want to delete a parent object and all its children using cascade in order to reduce the number of delete operations being performed.

So I have both entities like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public long ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and the child entity looks like

```
public class Child 
{
    public long ChildId { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

and I create the `TypeConfiguration` in order to use cascade delete

```
public class ParentTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Parents");
        this.HasKey(c => c.ParentId);

        this.HasMany(c => c.Children)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

and then I am ready to go. So far so good.

I create a test like the following to see that I am doing everything good...

```
[TestMethod]
public void RemoveParentEntity()
{
      var parent = new Parent() { ParentName = "name" };
      parent.Children = new Collection<Child>();
      parent.Children.Add(new Child() { ChildName = "child1" });
      parent.Children.Add(new Child() { ChildName = "child2" });

      var unitOfWork = new MyUnitOfWork();
      var repo = new ParentRepository(unitOfWork);            
      var count = repo.GetAll().Count();

      repo.Add(parent);
      repo.UnitOfWork.Commit();

      //unitOfWork = new MyUnitOfWork();
      //repo = new ParentRepository(unitOfWork);

      repo.Remove(cadenaAprobacion);
      repo.UnitOfWork.Commit();

      var result = repo.GetAll().Count();

      Assert.AreEqual(count, result);
}
```

This test fails saying:

> *The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.*

So I googled/binged this and I saw that I should make my dependent property optional since the child objects are being updated. So I did that in the entity and the `TypeConfiguration` and I was getting the error with a `DbUpdateException` with the typical I cannot update the child object, etc.

So now I am confused. In order to fix the test I know I can do 2 different things:

1. Remove the children objects before removing the parent object. This will make several operations in the database and this it is not what I wanted.
2. Create a new context, get the parent entity and remove the entity. This will work just fine and those are the lines commented previously in the test.

My question is, what is the correct thing to do when you have the child collection in the context and you want to use the cascade delete option in EF? How can I remove the objects from the context without making an operation in the database?

I am sure I am having a concept problem, I would like someone to point it out. So I learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: The plural of `child` in English is `children` (not `childs`)

Comment: I edited the code to reflect your comments. Thanks